# Simplifying a logic expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$p \Rightarrow q$  is true

Which is the logic value of $(p \vee r) \Rightarrow (q \vee r)$ ?

I did at this point and I can not siplify it more:

$\neg (p \vee r) \vee (q \vee r)$

$(\neg p \wedge \neg r) \vee ( q \vee r)$

Could someone help me please and explain how should I simplify it?

Comment: **Hint:** Either $r$ is true or it is false ...

Comment: Well, there is also a way to see this without assuming excluded middle ;)

Comment: because of associativity you can drop parentheses around $q \vee r$. And then combine the $r$ with the $\neg p \wedge \neg r$

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm , but when can I suppose that a letter is true or false?

Comment: Which one? @OlesWohnzimmer

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer: Sure, but when we assume that $a\to b$ is the same as to $\neg a\lor b$, we're already implicitly using classical logic anyway.

Comment: @FranciscaSousa: In classical logic you can _always_ assume that anything you can write down (such as, for example, $r$) is either true or false.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If truth value of $r$ is $T$, then $p\lor T\implies q\lor T\equiv (T\implies T)\equiv T$.

If truth value of $r$ is $F$, then $p\lor F\implies q\lor F\equiv (p\implies q)\equiv T$.